# Java Translate Point

Tags: java, point, translate

I know there is this method:

```
pt.translate(int x, int y);
```

But is there this method:

```
pt.translate(Point anotherPoint);
```

Would be the same as saying:

```
pt.translate(anotherPoint.x, anotherPoint.y);
```

But I thought there might be that method because it is simpler.

Comment: Seems more like an observation to me.. Is there an actual question here?

Comment: Sort of, seems like one of those things that Java would have, but could not find it anywhere :-)

Comment: Point? What? Do you mean java.awt.Point? You should specify; there are lots of Java Point implementations is libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html), that is the only translate method. So, as you've said,

```
pt.translate(anotherPoint.x, anotherPoint.y);
```

is what you're looking for.

Also, accessing the fields of an object is just about as simple as it gets :-)